# Jquery ajax call for generate authorization code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As part of my requirement, I would like to generate authorization code by calling O365 url from jquery ajax call. I am calling below script from document ready()

```
            $.ajax({                                                    
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant id}}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={{client id}}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://myurl.com/createpage/&response_mode=query&resource={{resource}}&state=9128',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(jsonData) {
                    alert(jsonData);
            },
            error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
              console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            cache: false
        });
```

But it is getting following error.
[Jquery ajax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3aRz.png)

Request you to help on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the content of the response in the tab network (in your dev tools).

I guess the response is not a valid json, so the parsing failed (your specified the jsonp type in your ajax call)